# What business logic can I share between my Android and iOS apps using Xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, mysql, sqlite, xamarin

I want to build an app that targets multiple platforms (Android and iOS) using Xamarin. This app consists of retrieving specific datas from MySQL database, store them in an internal database (using SQLite database for Android for example) and make a screen containing a list of products names to make it simple. Doing this, the device running my app can show the list offline. In addition to that, the client using my app (either Android device or iOS device) when it gets online, should be notified of modifications in the mysql database and update the internal database.

Creating this cross-platform Android and iOS app with Xamarin normally involves creating three types of projects:

- **A portable class library project that contains the shared code**
- **An Android application project containing the Android specific code**
- **An iOS application project containing the iOS specific code**

It's fairly easy to notice that the User Interface is the part that I can't share between Android and iOS. But I find it so difficult to find the part that can be shared between them.

Is it possible to share the logic of

- **Retrieving datas from MySQL database**?
- **Getting notifications when MySQL database is updated**?
- **Storing datas in an internal storage**?
- **Retrieving datas form the internal storage**?

Comment: If you've got classes to represent data objects, classes to perform storage/retrieval of such data, etc. in your shared library, then those other projects can utilize them. Logic like updating the UI must stay in the UI project, but logic like calculations can stay in the business logic part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shared project can (generally) contain anything that isn't platform or UI specific, like:

- data access
- domain models
- service code
- view models
- utility code

Also note that if you use Xamarin Forms you can also put your UI code in shared project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what's the difference between using Xamarin Forms for shared UI and using two seperate UIs for each platform?

Comment: If you want the greatest degree of control over your UI, and want to maximize the use of platform specific features, then write separate platform projects for your UI.  If you want to maximize code sharing, and are willing to (potentially) pay a small penalty in performance and loss of control, then consider using Forms.

Comment: With Xamarin Forms, you can use platform specific feature.